# How do i fill a list with zeros? When I try to .append(0), I am met with an error message saying that 'int' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, list, class

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self,num_rows=2,num_cols=2):
        '''
            WRITE DOCSTRING HERE!
        '''
        if num_rows <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Matrix: Error, the dimensions must be positive integers!")
        if num_cols <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Matrix: Error, the dimensions must be positive integers!")
        self.x = num_rows
        self.y = num_cols
        self.z = []
        for i in range(self.x):
            self.z.append([])
        for i in self.z:
            for i in range(len(self.z)):
                i.add(0)
        return self.z
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  python_unit_test line 10, in test_unit
    A = Matrix()
  File "proj11.py", line 32, in __init__
    i.add(0)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: You don't seem to use `self.y` anywhere. Isn't `z` supposed to be a `x * y` matrix?

Comment: I use 'self.y' later, this is just a part of a larger project. This is my first experience with classes so I am still trying to figure out what I am doing so it is bound to have some unnecessary inclusions. @Selcuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is defined twice in your nested loop, the 2nd `i` will overwrite the first. Rename one of them to avoid this. Also, `.add` should be `.append` and `range(len(self.z))` should probably be `range(self.y)` in order to have the correct number of columns.

```
for row in self.z:
    for _ in range(self.y):
        row.append(0)
```

Side note: why is `__init__` returning a value?

Comment: I didn't mean for there to be a return I left it in from when I was trying different things to make it work. This was my first time dealing with classes and didn't know how they worked. @SuperStormer